# Get the Value First Before the Form Shows up PHP

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, nested-forms

I'd like to show up to 10 email fields to submit on the form but only by selecting options from 1 - 10.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="select">
<select name="row">
<option value=1">1</option>
...
<option value="10">10</option
<input type="submit" name="select">
</form>
```

The next form shows up depending on the selected form

```
<form name="secondform">
<?php ... ?>  <!--for loop depending on the value above-->
<input name="email>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery as of yet. I'm just working on PHP :(

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you want a dropdown menu and you want to display the same amount of email address fields as you have selected in the menu.  So if you select 3, then three fields will show up.

Comment: Definatly client side. php can do absolutely nothing here, unless you want the select to submit the form on select and reload the page with the proper ammount of forms.

Comment: @CP510 yes I'm sure you can. But I like PHP. And I'm not working on any client-side language.

Comment: Then your going to have a hard time, and an annoying one to the user. PHP only executes on page load, and can't do anything after the initial page is delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have your dropdown, submit that value to either self or another php script that contains this:

```
$selected = $_POST['select'];

for($i = 0; $i<$selected; $i++){

     echo "<input type='text' name='email$i'>";

}
```

`$selected` is the value of the dropdown menu.

Now we have a for loop.  It set's `$i` to zero then says while `$i` is less than the value of your drop down value, add `1` more to `$i` and run `echo "<input type='text' name='email$i'>";`

As you can see, I appended `$i` to to `email` so that each field has it's own unique name.

What you can do as well is do just as [CP510](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2020356/cp510) says and add `onchange='this.form.submit()'` to the select tag so it is submitted automatically and I would submit the form to the same page.  This meaning set the action of the form of which the select menu is in to `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`.

---

I would **STRONGLY** recommend learning jQuery for something like this.

Here's the jQuery (mostly just plain javascript) version of this... it's very similar:

**Please make sure you put this in the head of your html file:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id='selected' onchange='addFields();'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='8'>8</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function addFields(){

    var selected = $('#selected').val();

    for(var i = 0; i<selected; i++){
         document.write('<input type="text" name="email' + i + '">'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: And add `onchange='this.form.submit()'` to the <select> tag for some fun auto-submiting

Comment: Thanks!  I'm working on a jsfiddle to give him as well.  Totally forgot about that.

Comment: @CP510 yeah I'm learning JS. I'm getting there. For some reason I like PHP and utilize it. I like it when you "view source" on the browser, you won't see all the back end codes. PHP just spits out HTML.

Comment: @mythoslife Yes, thats exactly why I use it. But theres a time and place for client side. The jQuery doesn't present a security risk here, its simply using the correct tools for the job. I personally hate sites that reload forms because of a simple event like this.

Comment: @CP510 I see. I know a lot use combo of all these languages. Thanks.

Comment: Basically this is the best analogy I can come up with. You have a small plate of food at a table, you want more. But instead of using the large plate of extras with the spoon in it on the table, your going to walk back to the kitchen and make the chef refill it. Use the spoon. :)

Comment: Hello guys there's away to show the first form first then the second just by using PHP only (of course with HTML). First to show the form if first form isn't sent, if it is, then (the else statement) show the next).

Comment: Are you asking how to do this or do you know?